# Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char' [-fpermissive] 16 | A[++top] = x; | ^ | | | char*

Tags: c, data-structures

> I am trying to add strings to the stack. Please tell me what's wrong in the program.
> In this program, I am trying to implement the stack as a data structure. I know how to add numbers to the stack and / or remove them, but I don't know how to add character input. Right now I want to do something like a list of items and then print the whole list.

```
//Array implementation of the stack
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 11

char A[MAX_SIZE];
int top = -1;


void Push(char x[])
{
  if (top == MAX_SIZE - 1) {
    printf("Error! Array size: %d exceeded\n", MAX_SIZE);
    return;
  }
  A[++top] = x;
}

void Pop() {
  if (top == -1) {
    printf("Error! No element to pop\n");
    return;
  }
  top--;
}

char Top()
{
  return A[top];
}

void Print()
{
  int i;
  printf("Stack: ");
  for (i = 0; i <= top; i++)
    printf("%s ", A[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
  char name1[10] = "Pablo";
  Push(name1);
  char name2[10] = "Robert";
  Push(name2);
  Print();
}
```

> invalid conversion from 'char' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
> 16 | A[++top] = x;
> | ^
> | |
> | char*

Comment: `char A[MAX_SIZE]` can only hold *one copy* of the string passed, which must be by `strcpy()`. I guess you wanted `char *a[MAX_STACK]` which is an array of pointers.

Comment: `A[++top]` is a `char`, `x` is a `char*`, so what do you expect?

Comment: Are you sure the error message is saying "from 'char' to 'char'" and not "from 'char*' to 'char'"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of the array

```
char A[MAX_SIZE];
```

are `char`, which can store only one character.

On the other hand, the argument `x` is `char*` (`char x[]` has the same meaning as `char* x` in function arguments). Therefore type mismatch occurs.

Changing the array to

```
char* A[MAX_SIZE];
```

and the function `Top` to

```
char* Top()
```

will make your program work.

Note that then the pointers will be directly stored instead of copying strings, so be careful not to dereferenced pointers to vanished object. (This won't be problem in this code)

Answer (score 0):

Your stack `A` is declared as an array of `char`, so it can only hold a single string (or an array of characters).  In the line in question, you're attempting to assign a `char *` to a single `char`.

You should instead define `A` as an array of `char *`:

```
char *A[MAX_SIZE];
```